# Python Sqlite3 get value from table, like a dictionary

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a database with values like this stored in a .db file. [UUID : INTEGER]

```sql
1e1f3e6e-c6e6-4897-8bb8-d732a1f5b303 : 12

2b0978c1-3f5b-4c7e-9151-231e0a21d2e3 : 128

4eba65c7-b02f-4627-8205-172333951d39 : 1

4baa130f-fe5b-45c7-9a44-842a6544d4a9 : 73

99fc3095-0aaa-4b19-aa2e-65b027bfd6ad : 7342
```

I would like to use the UUID to get an integer, like you would in a dictionary. Such as `mydatabase["99fc3095-0aaa-4b19-aa2e-65b027bfd6ad"]` would return 7342. So far all I have seen about getting values does not work in this way.

Comment: Are `UUID : INTEGER` 2 separate columns or one column?

Comment: you could make `mydatabase` a custom object that does some sql calls in the background when it gets passed a string like that, i think.  Or if you could live with `mydatabase('uid')` make it a function, that'll be even easier

Comment: They are in separate columns

Comment: Have you tried using a `where` clause?

Comment: I think I have something working, but it returns <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000025896C8A110> instead

Comment: Do you need a mapper class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily implement such class.

```
class DBMap:
    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('map.db')

    def __getitem__(self, uuid):
        val = self.conn.execute(
            'select val from m where uuid = ?', (uuid,)
        ).fetchone()
        if val:
            return val[0]
        else:
            raise KeyError
```

On `__init__`, the connection to database is established and it is closed when `__del__`eted.
`__getitem__` is to implement evaluation of `self[key]`. So you can do the following:

```
dbm = DBMap()
print(dbm['aaa'])
```

Here is the `.schema` I used.

```
create table m (
    uuid TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    val  INTEGER
)
```